# RSpec - Can't find spec/spec_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails 4 book and can't find the `spec/spec_helper.rb`. This is the link to his book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and I'm working on Chapter 3 Test driven development section.

I ran this code to invoked RSpec and static_pages_spec.rb

```
$ rails generate integration_test static_pages      
invoke  rspec      
create    spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

After this I need to add the Capybara DSL to the RSpec helper file.

```
spec/spec_helper.rb

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate spec:install'
…
RSpec.configure do |config|  
.  .  .  
config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

PROBLEM: my problem is that I can't find or open `spec/spec_helper.rb`. I've tried `$subl spec/spec_helper.rb` but it only opened an empty text editor file.

Added Followings to my Gemfile for RSpec and TDD:

```
group :development, :test do  
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'  
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do  
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'  
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end
```

Ran:

```
$ bundle install --without production
$ bundle update
$ bundle install
$ rails generate rspec:install
$ rails generate integration_test static_pages
```

After this point, I'm suppose to open `spec/sepc_helper.rb` and add the `CapybaraDSL` and run this `$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`. Since I couldn't find the `spec_helper.rb`, I just ran it on my terminal to see what happens and got following error:

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

I'm not sure why I can't find spec_helper. I read the other tutorials and it seems like spec_helper file automatically forms when they load RSpec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check Gemfile for:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
end
```

run `bundle install` command at console:

after `rails generate rspec:install`

try in a bash at project folder:

```
find -name spec_helper.rb
```

there is a complete referece for `Rspec` usage with rails: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Answer (score 5):

Double check that you are running `rspec spec/` from the root rails directory and not from within the spec directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the rspec gem installed. You can do this by declaring it in your Gemfile

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

In Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
end
```

`bundle install`

`bundle exec rails generate rspec:install`

Those steps will create what's needed to run rspec.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth mentioning that occasionally I try to run rspec in a folder other than the root directory and this is the error that pops up.  I seem to recall that this can be modified somehow, but not sure how.